# Trouble using a For loop for Target.Value2 property range

Tags: vba, excel

In one of my workbooks I have run into an issue in the Worksheet Change event when attempting to change the case to Proper in a range of cell values using the Target.Value2 property.

Using the code below, when I change a single cell, the case is changed to Proper as expected. When pasting multiple cells, the case is changed to Proper for each value in the Locals window when stepping through the code, but the values pasted into the cells are not Proper case.

Thanks in advance!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo Error:

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I2:J999")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = StrConv(Target.Value, vbProperCase)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            For Each Value In Target.Value2
            Value = StrConv(Value, vbProperCase)
            Next Value

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Exit Sub
    End If

Exit Sub

Error:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    If Application.ScreenUpdating = False Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If Application.EnableEvents = False Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (you need to define the variable types!)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo Err

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I2:J999")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Dim cel as Range 'Define the type of variable formally Value
        For Each cel In Target 'Will work for one cell or multiples
            cel.Value = StrConv(cel.Value, vbProperCase)
        Next cel

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        Exit Sub
    End If

Exit Sub

Err:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    If Application.ScreenUpdating = False Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If Application.EnableEvents = False Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer works like a charm, thanks for the help!

I forgot that a defined range would work for a single record. (I am way out of practice!)

Changing 'Value = StrConv(Value, vbProperCase)' to 'Target.Value2 = StrConv(Value, vbProperCase)' also worked in my original code. For whatever reason my code was working with Value undeclared until closing and reopening my workbook.

Thank again!